# Storing a variable from a class within a class (tkinter)

Tags: class, tkinter, scope, python-3.4

I am trying to capture the entry value from the pop up window into a variable that I can access later and manipulate. I need to make a lists of several message box entries to generate questions for the user. However, whenever I try to capture it the variable I assign it to comes up empty.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
topFrame = Frame(root)
topFrame.pack()

class popupWindowID (object):
  def __init__(self,master):
    top=self.top=Toplevel(master)
    self.label=Label(top,text="ID")
    self.label.pack()
    self.entrybox=Entry(top)
    self.entrybox.pack()
    self.b=Button(top,text='Enter',command=self.cleanup)
    self.b.pack()
  def cleanup(self):  # This cleans it up so it can be overwritten if needed
    self.value=str(self.entrybox.get())
    self.top.destroy()

class mainWindow(object): 

 def __init__(self,master):
    self.master=master
    self.ID=Button(topFrame,text="ID", command=self.popupID)
    self.ID.pack(side = TOP)

    self.info=Button(topFrame,text="Show Test Information",command=self.entryValue)
    self.info.pack(side = TOP)

 def popupID(self):
    self.ID=popupWindowID(self.master)
    self.master.wait_window(self.ID.top)

 def entryValue(self):
    print(self.ID.value)
m=mainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can not reproduce. `print(self.ID.value)` in `entryValue` prints the previously entered value.

Comment: Works for me too, tested on Python 2.5